# Two training ops for slim.learning.train (TensorFlow, TF-Slim)

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

Some architectures require two or more training ops (for example, in GAN you need to train a generator and discriminator). How can you achieve that with TF-Slim training functions? As far as I can see slim.learning.train takes only one training op.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum the training ops created by slim.learning.create_train_op. A train_op is just a tensor that will update the parameters when evaluated and return the loss. If you add two training ops both will be evaluated (in parallel).

Answer (score 0):

You can overide `train_step_fn`, which is the main body function when running `slim.learning.train()`.

For example, suppose you have `train_op1` and `train_op2`, set `train_ops = [train_op1, train_op2]`, and then you can try the following:

```
def train_step_fn(session, train_ops, global_step, train_step_kwargs):
  session.run(train_ops[0], ...)
  session.run(train_ops[1], ...)
  ...

slim.learning.train(train_step_fn=train_step_fn, ...)
```